# javascript push() method for adding object to array of objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
var model = {
  cats: [
    {
        clickCount: 0,
        name: "Panther",
        imgUrl: "images/cat1.png"           
    },
    {
        clickCount: 0,
        name: "Tiger",
        imgUrl: "images/cat2.png"           
    },
    {
        clickCount: 0,
        name: "Rocky",
        imgUrl: "images/cat3.png"           
    },
    {
        clickCount: 0,
        name: "Marshal",
        imgUrl: "images/cat4.png"           
    },
    {
        clickCount: 0,
        name: "Simpson",
        imgUrl: "images/cat5.png"           
    },
    {
        clickCount: 0,
        name: "Kajol",
        imgUrl: "images/cat6.png"           
    }
  ]
};
catObject = {
                name: document.getElementById('text-name').value,
                url: document.getElementById('text-url').value,
                count: document.getElementById('text-count').value
            };
```

model is an array of objects. I am trying to add another object using model.cats.push(catObject); 
where text-name, text-url, text-count are ids of textboxes in a form.
I am not getting desired results. I am seeing that only catObject.name is getting pushed onto model.cats and catObject.url and catObject.count is not getting added and hence 'undefined' are values of the model.cats.imgUrl and model.cats.clickCount.
I can add full code if required. I tried so may things.. Could someone check if I am missing anything here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: missing line: `cats.push(catObject);`

Comment: You're naming the properties differently in `catObject` than the existing objects in `cats`. `url` instead of `imgUrl`; `count` instead of `clickCount`. Just change those property names.

Comment: thanks you Mike. That worked like magic.

Comment: Mike, how can I mark your reply as answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Correction**

`model` is not an array of objects rather `model` is an object that contains a property (i.e. `cats`) which is an array of objects.

**You're correct**

From your description, it is clear that you have successfully pushed `catObject` into `cats` using `model.cats.push(catObject);`

**What went wrong**

You might have used `loop` to access the elements inside `cats` array and got `undefined` for `model.cats.clickCount` and `model.cats.imgUrl` of only the last object you've pushed because you named properties of `catObject` as `url` and `count` (i.e. instead of `imgUrl` and `clickCount`). So, just change the property names to `imgUrl` and `clickCount` to fix the issue.

[Corrected code here](https://jsbin.com/sufewal/edit?js,console)